# Create record using aerospike operate command

Tags: aerospike

I am trying following code. Getting "key not found" error. I want to know whether it is possible to create a record using aerospike multi ops.

```
public long incrementSingle(String counterName, long by){

        // Create a key
        Key recordKey = new Key(Constants.NAMESPACE, Constants.SINGLE_SET, counterName);

        // Increment operation
        Bin incrementCounter = new Bin(Constants.SINGLE_COUNTER_BIN, by);

        // https://www.aerospike.com/docs/client/java/usage/kvs/multiops.html#operation-specification
        Record record = asClient.operate(null, recordKey, 
                            Operation.add(incrementCounter), 
                            Operation.get(Constants.SINGLE_COUNTER_BIN));

        return record.getLong(Constants.SINGLE_COUNTER_BIN);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think for add() to work, the record must exist before. Test with creating the record referred by recordKey with some initial value (say initialize to 0) in the counter bin and then increment it. The Operation API for add() does not specifically point this out, but I am just guessing because add() will first read existing record on disk and is perhaps not finding it.  (Edit: See further definitive test/clarification per Write Policy used in the comments below.)

Comment: Suppose I want to store the number of visits of users. I can't use operate function as most of the time visitors will be unique and their record will not exist.

Comment: issue is not operate - its the add api (again i am assuming that is the issue)

Comment: No reason for it not to work. You're not giving the complete code, so I can't see what's up with your policies, but the default behavior of Aerospike is to upsert. If the record doesn't exist this record will be created with the numeric value set to the increment value you gave it. See my answer above with an example of how it works.

Comment: Tested. Depends on write policy for RecordExistsAction. Will work with default write policy of RecordExistsAction.UPDATE (Java client) but if you were using RecordExistsAction.UPDATE_ONLY, it will fail.  In the example code, it is set to null, so then it depends if the defaults have been overwritten. With UPDATE_ONLY, add() gives key not found error.  Exception in thread "main" com.aerospike.client.AerospikeException: Error ... 127.0.0.1 3000: Key not found
 at com.aerospike.client.command.WriteCommand.parseResult(WriteCommand.java:75).  Works with Operation.add() also if policy is UPDATE.

Comment: Also, check for typos between the code you shared here and actual code on Key object created vs used.  Just a thought.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any problem with this. Here's some Python code that does the same:

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import print_function
import aerospike
from aerospike import exception as e
from aerospike_helpers.operations import operations as oh
import sys

config = {"hosts": [("192.168.243.133", 3000)]}
try:
    client = aerospike.client(config).connect()
except e.ClientError as e:
    print("Error: {0} [{1}]".format(e.msg, e.code))
    sys.exit(2)

key = ("test", "demo", "count-this")
print("Nuke the record")
try:
    client.remove(key)
except:
    pass
ops = [oh.increment("counter", 2), oh.read("counter")]
meta = {"ttl": aerospike.TTL_NEVER_EXPIRE}
for i in range(4):
    try:
        k, m, b = client.operate_ordered(key, ops, meta)
        print("Iteration {0}: bin value is {1}".format(i, b))
    except e.RecordError as e:
        print("Error: {0} [{1}]".format(e.msg, e.code))
        sys.exit(4)
client.close()
```

Resulting in the expected

```
Nuke the record
Iteration 0: bin value is [('counter', 2)]
Iteration 1: bin value is [('counter', 4)]
Iteration 2: bin value is [('counter', 6)]
Iteration 3: bin value is [('counter', 8)]
```